# How to find the last 10 rows of first two columns in a data frame using python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to access the last 10 rows of the first two columns of a data frame in python called `index`

```
index.tail(10).index.iloc[:,0:2]
```

But I get the following error:

```
RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'iloc
```

Comment: what library are you using for your dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12fg1MpIJeVM03-DGgLr39v4D1k97bR10

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"datax": range(10, 64, 8), 
"datay": range(0, 84 ,12)}) # 2 columns with 7 data points

print(df) # print dataset
print(df.iloc[-2:,:1]) 
# get last two rows of the first column using iloc
```

You can use iloc to perform advanced indexing on dataframes. An example can be found on the Colab link I have shared.

Answer (score -1):

To find the last 10 rows of first two columns in a data frame using python you can use:

```
df.iloc[-10:, 0:2]
```

Comment: I think this is an attempt to answer.